# Is there a framework or method that lets the server and client easily share variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have variables stored in json that the client needs to read but I don't want the user to have to download them all due to the huge file size.  Is there a nodejs framework that makes it relatively easy for client and server to share variables?

Comment: Wouldn't I need to load the entire file though?  I want the client to ask the server for just one variable among thousands.

Answer (score 3):

There's this module called [Now](https://github.com/Flotype/now) which seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

[Meteor](http://meteor.com/) is a stack that takes full advantage of websockets, making the client/server realm a continuum.

It uses JSON RPC, and does not rely on huge REST collections - this approach has pros and cons, but it's up to you investigate further.

Comment: I'm actually considering Meteor, but in order for that to work I *think* I need to write a meteor method for every variable in order to make the client and server talk to each other.  I was wondering if there was something else that would let me avoid doing that!  If it wasn't for that I'd use Meteor, definitely.